# jquery form validation internet explorer problems

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Again Internet Explorer is going me crazy. I am using [bassistance FORM jvalidation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Form validations works perfect on Chrome, Safari, Opera, Firefox (win and OSX), but it does not work with IE7. IE7 does not show me any errors...

Please could you help me?
Please see my code bellow at [fiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/BWajn/2/)

Answer (score 1):

It works for me fine everywhere(even IE7), I can only see an error in IE7, due to Access issue for your js files in fiddle.

Comment: thank you, yes it works but it seems that this code crash with other js codes I use, but I don't know what, my form code, is exactly the same :(